# Qt - qcombobox with multiple columns

Tags: sql, qt

I'm trying show QTableView in QComboBox.

Example Department is table in my database.

Query =

> SELECT Dep.Code,Dep.Name FROM Dep

and I've tried this my code.

```
QSqlQueryModel* depModel = new QSqlQueryModel();
depModel->setQuery("SELECT Dep.Code,Dep.Name FROM Dep");
.
.
.
QTableView* cboxTable = new QTableView(this);
cboxTable->setModel(depModel);
QComboBox *courseComboBox = new QComboBox();
courseComboBox->setView(cboxTable);
```

but not work.Where is my problem ? I want see multiple columns.

Comment: It is better to explain the actual result, too, on top "but not work".

Comment: It's not work,if I'm trying like this code,combobox will empty and not used

Comment: Why do you need table within a combo box?

Comment: actually I needn't but my query return two value.one of code and other name.I can show code or name in combo box but I want show code and name together.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] ) or the '+' Operator.

This following select should return one String for your Combobox.

```
SELECT (Dep.Code + ' ' + Dep.Name) as Name FROM Dep;
```

Comment: Sure, this's the sql way. I guess only way for this question.